# Code does not work on 64 bit Office

Tags: excel, vba

I should figure out problem with excel VBA code compatibility on 64bit systems. I do not use VB language and code below is not my but I have to solve that issue.

Excel VB code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal CodePage As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, ByVal cchWideChar As Long, ByRef lpMultiByteStr As Byte, ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, ByVal lpDefaultChar As String, ByRef lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As Long

Private Const CP_UTF8 As Long = 65001
Private Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER As Long = 122&


Public Function ToUTF8(s As String) As Byte()

  If Len(s) = 0 Then Exit Function


  Dim ccb As Long
  ccb = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(s), Len(s), ByVal 0&, 0, vbNullString, ByVal 0&)

  If ccb = 0 Then
    Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error."
  End If

  Dim b() As Byte
  ReDim b(1 To ccb)

  If WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(s), Len(s), b(LBound(b)), ccb, vbNullString, ByVal 0&) = 0 Then
    Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error."
  Else
    ToUTF8 = b
  End If

End Function
```

I have tried to add conditions `#If VBA7` and `PtrSave` to everywhere but worksheet still does not work.

This is the code that I tried in Office 64 Bit

```
    Option Explicit

    #If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32" (ByVal CodePage As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpWideCharStr As LongPtr, ByVal cchWideChar As Long, ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, ByVal cchMultiByte As LongPtr, ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As LongPtr
    #Else
Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal CodePage As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, ByVal cchWideChar As Long, ByRef lpMultiByteStr As Byte, ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, ByVal lpDefaultChar As String, ByRef lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As Long
    #EndIf

    Private Const CP_UTF8 As Long = 65001
    Private Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER As Long = 122&


    Public Function ToUTF8(s As String) As Byte()

      If Len(s) = 0 Then Exit Function


      Dim ccb As LongPtr
      ccb = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(s), Len(s), ByVal 0&, 0, vbNullString, ByVal 0&)

      If ccb = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error."
      End If

      Dim b() As Byte
      ReDim b(1 To ccb) // ERROR TYPE MISMATCH on ccb

      If WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(s), Len(s), b(LBound(b)), ccb, vbNullString, ByVal 0&) = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error."
      Else
        ToUTF8 = b
      End If

    End Function
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: This code will not work on Office 64 bit as you need to change the API declarations. See [THIS](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp) link. `I have tried to add conditions #If VBA7 and PtrSave to everywhere but woksheet still does not work` Can you show us the exact code that you tried in 64bit Office?

Comment: When I debug code above in excel then I will get error message "TYPE MISMATCH" in this part "ReDim b(1 To ccb)"...

Comment: After I changed type LongPtr to Long then error "type mismatch" occurred on this line (program highlights function name): ccb = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(s), Len(s), ByVal 0&, 0, vbNullString, ByVal 0&)

Comment: Still the same error "type mismatch" (program highlights function name)

Comment: Did you make the 4th change? I was editing the post when you replied. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: You are right. I had to refresh page. Now, this module is working but next error occured in module for save XML file. Module for save XML uses function which you have repaired. It is quite long piece of code. Can I paste it here?

Comment: Well that goes as a separate question ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I sent file for testing if there is an error somewhere in data. If not then I will create separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Untested)

Change

---

This

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal CodePage As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpWideCharStr _
As LongPtr, ByVal cchWideChar As Long, ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
ByVal cchMultiByte As LongPtr, ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, _
ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As LongPtr
```

To

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "Kernel32" ( _
ByVal CodePage As LongPtr, ByVal dwflags As LongPtr, _
ByVal lpWideCharStr As LongPtr, ByVal cchWideChar As LongPtr, _
ByVal lpMultiByteStr As LongPtr, ByVal cchMultiByte As LongPtr, _
ByVal lpDefaultChar As LongPtr, ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As LongPtr) As LongPtr
```

---

This

```
Private Const CP_UTF8 As Long = 65001
```

To

```
Private Const CP_UTF8 = 65001
```

---

This

```
Private Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER As Long = 122&
```

To

```
Private Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122&
```

---

This

```
Dim ccb As LongPtr
```

To

```
Dim ccb As Variant
```

In the last three chnages that I suggested, we are declaring them as Variants because we don't know what the type will be on different systems. It will either be `Long` or `LongPtr`

Comment: fails on the first line: WideCharToMultiByte with type mismatch.

When I change to 

WideCharToMultiByte(VarPtr(CP_UTF8), 0, StrPtr(s), VarPtr(Len(s)), ByVal VarPtr(0&), 0, StrPtr(vbNullString), ByVal VarPtr(0&))

it returns zero and raises the error two lines later.