# vba PtrSafe function type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, native, declare, type-mismatch

I changed a declaration to PtrSafe and now its failing on type-mismatch. 
I changed the problematic params, removing StrPtr and VarPtr, and it's still giving me a type-mismatch.

The following code (for converting unicode16 strings to a UTF8 byte-array) is failing. I had to change the declaration to PtrSafe otherwise the declaration code stayed red. After adding the PtrSafe I now get a type mismatch, showing me where the mistake was.

I changed the types so they now fit in the calling code, (by removing the StrPtr and ArrPtr marked by the compiler as the mismatch culprit) and now  get a general Type Mismatch message. What do I need to do?!

Here's my code, and the errors I get:

```
''' WinApi function that maps a UTF-16 (wide character) string to a new character string
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel64" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As Long

Private Const CP_UTF8 = 65001 ' CodePage constant for UTF-8


''' Return byte array with VBA "Unicode" string encoded in UTF-8
Public Function Utf8BytesFromString(strInput As String) As Byte()
    Dim nBytes As Long
    Dim abBuffer() As Byte
    ' Get length in bytes *including* terminating null
    nBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal strInput, -1, vbNull, 0&, 0&, 0&) 
' Error!  This gives unspecified Type Mismatch
' whereas before when was defined as 
' nBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal StrPtr(strInput), -1, vbNull, 0&, 0&, 0&)
' it gave a specified Type Mismatch, marking in blue the StrPtr 

' We don't want the terminating null in our byte array, so ask for `nBytes-1` bytes
    ReDim abBuffer(nBytes - 2)  ' NB ReDim with one less byte than you need
    nBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal strInput, -1, ByVal abBuffer(0), nBytes - 1, 0&, 0&) 
    Utf8BytesFromString = abBuffer
    ' this too failed with Type Mismatch on StrPtr and VarPtr when defined as 
    ' nBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal StrPtr(strInput), -1, ByVal VarPtr(abBuffer(0)), nBytes - 1, 0&, 0&)

End Function

Public Sub Tryit()
    Dim sht as WorkSheet
    Dim bytArr() As Byte
    Dim str as string
    Set sht = Sheets(1)
    str = sht.Cells(1,1) ' a string with gibberish imported incorrectly from a UTF8 file
    bytArr = Utf8BytesFromString(str) 
End Sub
```

The original code was taken from [a post on the DI Managment website](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html))

The differences between this question and [a similar question, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982682/code-does-not-work-on-64-bit-office) (which supposedly has an answer, but one which DOES NOT WORK, and DOES NOT EXPLAIN WHY OR WHAT THEY DID) are:

a. I point out in the title and question that the issue is also a general issue, with PtrSafe and 64 bit.

b. I give the source of the code.

c. I changed both the declaration and the calling code only for POINTERS while NOT changing the direct parameters. I can safely suppose that is the reason their answer is still failing. Anyone answering my question, (and getting it to work) would also show how and what needs changing, while in the other question all you need to do is solve the code, and leave the programmers guessing why and what to do with similar code (such as that found on the thread where this code was found).

Comment: And if I change the type in the delcaration to LongPtr it gives me a "file not found" in "kernal 64"

Comment: I just edited the question and explained how it is different from the supposedly duplicate one. (I also commented there that it doesn't work and what the error I get is.)